# Click radiobutton to open iframe using Fancybox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have a normal marked up HTML page where an user can choose one option from 3 radio buttons.

[o] Option 1

[o] Option 2

[o] Option 3

However, when they click on the radiobutton for option 2, a pop up must open displaying a page.

I installed Fancybox (which already works! for those who not know it's a lightbox alternative) that opens a page in an iframe.

I have a text test link on the site:

```
<a id="example1" href="http://www.url.com/pages/newpage.php?iframe">test</a>
```

So basically, when I now click on "test", Fancybox opens displaying newpage.php.

This ALREADY works. But now I need to make it so that when you click radio button for option 2, it opens that page. I tried:

```
<input type="radio" id="example1" name="wnf" value="geven" onclick="window.open='http://www.url.com/pages/newpage.php?iframe'" /> Option 2
```

This does not work. Idea's?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to attach fancybox to your radio button, and set the source of the image to show in the options, see an example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/HYAxy/2/):

```
    $("#yourRabioBtnSelector").fancybox({
        target: this,
        href: 'url_of_the_image'
    });
```

Comment: Example works nice, almost what I need. But I do not want to open an image when I click the radiobutton, but I want it to display an iframe. How do I change that?